# Windows 7 toggle energy saving based on workload

Tags: windows-7, cpu, gpu

Is there a tool or function in Windows 7 to toogle energy saving based on the current cpu / gpu workload.

- Should work instantly
- Should toogle between **maximum energy saving** and **maximum power**
  (without any loss of cpu / gpu power)

Background: Gaming PC with overclocked CPU (i7) and GPU (NVIDIA 970) that is also used for low workloads. C-States are enabled.

Comment: I think "balanced" profile somewhat does what you want out of the box. With low CPU load, it will not cause **CPU** to draw more power than in "maximum energy saving" profile, whilst allowing full CPU utilization when under high load. Also, portion of the actual energy saving in "maximum energy saving" profile comes from quicker sleep/hibernate timeouts, lower screen brightness, low power wireless mode and so on.

Comment: Yeah I knew about the balanced profile, it's not really what I was looking for. Ideally there would be a third party software (wouldn't mind to pay for it) that does exactly as I described. The ice on the cake would be optional undervolting, underclocking profiles for cpu / gpu resp. provision of access to profiles of e.g. MSI afterburner and toggling those. Manual switching works, so why not automate it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

MSI Afterburner supports a 2D and 3D profile (settings->profile), that should auto switch between 2 profiles for the gpu based on present 3D workload.

No solution for the cpu or the rest of the systems though except the suggested "balanced" profile of Windows 7.